# Comparing excel rows across multiple tables and copying

Tags: excel, vba

I've worked on this for about a week and I'm stuck. I didn't see any forms with my problem on here, so hopefully y'all can help.

I'm trying to compare data from **sheet2** to **sheet1** and if the value in column **B** is the same, paste the data from **sheet2** in the next blank cell in **sheet1**

I've included a spreadsheet that hopefully illustrates my point better.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096893/copy-cell-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-depending-on-matching-column-values-in

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(sheet2!B(some_number)=sheet1!B(some_number),fill_in_answer_you_want,0)
```

You would have to input this statement into the cell that you want.  For example, in Cell C2 you would write:

```
=if(sheet2!$B2 = $B2,sheet2!$B2,0)
```

As for a way to fill in the next blank cell, you would have to write a vba script to find the cell you would like to place it in and place the above formula into the cell.